# howto find xml-attributes in xml-files directory?

Tags: xml, regex, grep

I have a bunch of xml-files and need to find any occurances of combined attributes.

Example:

```
<combobox name="myCombo" label="The combo:" data="apple:Apple|lemon:Lemon" />
```

I want to know which files and where I have a match in

```
"<combobox && data"
```

What would be the linux/grep command to use?

Is there any free find-tool for windows that would be appropriate?

(The files aren't pure xml, so parsing isn't an option)

regards,

Comment: What do you mean by match in combobox && data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to search multiple xml files using `GNU grep`:

```
grep -H "<combobox" *.xml | grep "data"
```

Here's another way to do the same thing with a single `grep` call:

```
grep -HE "<combobox.*data|data.*<combobox" *.txt
```

Note that technically you don't need the `-H` option, because you are searching multiple files. You really only need the `-H` flag if you're searching a single file.

Comment: Great, grep -En "<combobox.*data=" *.txt worked perfectly. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jtidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) to fix your files and then, [xsltprox+xsl](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html) to 'grep' the fixed xml files.